# Linux Kernel Reading/Writing

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to do placement and reading of blocks of a file in different extents of LVM. I am working on linux 4.7.2 :

git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

I have modified the following files :

1. linux-stable/fs/ext4/file.c
2. linux-stable/fs/dax.c
3. linux-stable/fs/ext4/extents.c
4. linux-stable/fs/ext4/inode.c

But I am getting following error :

```
include/linux/export.h:63:39: error: section attribute cannot be specified for local variables
  __visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym \

include/linux/export.h:63:39: error: declaration of ‘__ksymtab___dax_fault’ with no linkage follows extern declaration
  __visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym \

fs/dax.c:1090:19: error: non-static declaration of ‘dax_fault’ follows static declaration
 EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(dax_fault);
fs/dax.c:1099:13: error: invalid storage class for function ‘__dax_dbg’
 static void __dax_dbg(struct buffer_head *bh, unsigned long address,

fs/dax.c:1298:19: error: non-static declaration of ‘__dax_pmd_fault’ follows static declaration
 EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(__dax_pmd_fault);
```

Modified dax.c :

static int dax_insert_mapping() :

```
if(mapping->host->i_ino==15){
        if(block==0){
            for(my_i=0;my_i<my_dax_size;my_i++){
                fill_array[my_i]=0;
            }
        }
        for(my_i=0;my_i<my_dax_size;my_i++){
            printk(KERN_INFO "check %d fill %d\t",check_array[my_i],fill_array[my_i]);
        }
        my_block = (int) block;
        if(check_array[my_block]==0){
            if(fill_array[my_block]==0){
                fill_array[my_block]=1;
                goto my_atomic;
            }
            else if(fill_array[my_block]==1){
                for(my_i=my_block;my_i<=(my_dax_size-my_block);my_i++){
                    if(fill_array[my_i]==0 && check_array[my_i]==0){
                        dax.sector = dax.sector+(8*(my_i - my_block));
                        for(my_j=my_block;my_j<=my_i;my_j++){
                            fill_array[my_j] = 1;
                        }   
                    goto my_atomic;
                    }
                }
                //if(my_i==8){
                    printk(KERN_INFO "I'm at error!!!\n");
                    dax_flag =1;
                    goto my_return;
                //}

            }
        }
        else if(check_array[my_block]==1){
            if(fill_array[my_block]==0){
            for(my_i=my_block;my_i<=(my_dax_size-my_block);my_i++){
                if(check_array[my_i]==0){
                    dax.sector = dax.sector+(8*(my_i - my_block));
                    for(my_j=my_block;my_j<=my_i;my_j++){
                        fill_array[my_j] = 1;
                    }   
                    goto my_atomic;
                }
            }
            }
            else if(fill_array[my_block]==1){
                for(my_i=my_block;my_i<=(my_dax_size-my_block);my_i++){
                    if(fill_array[my_i]==0 && check_array[my_i]==0){
                        dax.sector = dax.sector+(8*(my_i - my_block));
                        for(my_j=my_block;my_j<=my_i;my_j++){
                            fill_array[my_j] = 1;
                        }   
                    goto my_atomic;
                    }
                }
                //if(my_i==8){
                    printk(KERN_INFO "I'm at error!!!\n");
                    dax_flag =1;
                    goto my_return;
                //}

            }   

        }
    }


my_atomic:
    printk(KERN_INFO "insert_mapping sector %lu\n",dax.sector);
    if (dax_map_atomic(bdev, &dax) < 0){
        printk(KERN_INFO "error at map_atomic\n");
        return PTR_ERR(dax.addr);
    }
    dax_unmap_atomic(bdev, &dax);
    my_addr = (unsigned long) dax.addr;
    ret = dax_insert_mapping_entry(mapping, vmf, entry, dax.sector);
    if (IS_ERR(ret)){
        printk(KERN_INFO "error at insert_mapping %lu\n",my_addr);
        return PTR_ERR(ret);
    }
    *entryp = ret;
    if(mapping->host->i_ino>11 && mapping->host->i_ino<=15){
        printk(KERN_INFO "inode #%lu: block %lu pgoff %lu sector %lu addr %lu pfn %llu size %ld dax_flag %d\n",mapping->host->i_ino,vmf->pgoff,block,dax.sector,my_addr,dax.pfn.val, dax.size,dax_flag);

        }

my_return:
    if(dax_flag==0)
    return vm_insert_mixed(vma, vaddr, dax.pfn);
    else
    return retval
```

Comment: How you modified dax.c?

Comment: Fork a Linux kernel on Github and create your branch with the patch(es). After share a link.